# Pass the response body with next

Tags: javascript, express

I'm pretty new to JavaScript so I'm still trying to figure things out. In the app we use `jwt` to check if a token is valid. For this, the following function is created using a tutorial and some of my own experimentation:

```js
function isAuthorized(req, res, next) {
    const bearerHeader = req.headers['authorization']

    if (typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
        let token = bearerHeader.split(' ')[1]
        let privateKey = 'secretkey'

        jwt.verify(token, privateKey, { algorithm: "HS256" }, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                res.sendStatus(403)
            }
            else {
                next()
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        res.sendStatus(403)
    }
}
```

When I then do a `post` call with some `json` payload in it, it will pass correctly in the following function:

```js
app.post('/api/posts', isAuthorized, (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: 'Post created',
        request: req.body.username
    })
})
```

The only thing that doesn't seem to work is how to consult the `json` paybload in the `body` that was sent with the `post` call. It surely must be possible to have the middleware function `isAuthorized` have this data passed on.

Comment: Hello, Could you elaborate a bit, where are you stuck?
I think I know the answer but not sure that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Sure, if I do a a post call with a valid token to the route `/posts`, I can reach that route without a problem. But if the `post` contains a json body like `@{userName: 'Bob'}`, I would like to be able to use the `userName` in the function after `isAuthorized`.

Comment: It also seems difficult to identify which user it is. As that information is stored in the token. But I can't seem to retrieve it.

Comment: Can't you set any header inside your req.body from your `isAuthorized`middleware that will help you in checking for the exact user inside the actual route handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out multiple options to achieve that

### Approach 1:

### Using [res.locals](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals), it is guaranteed to hold state over the life of a request.

An object that contains response local variables scoped to the request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during that request / response cycle (if any). Otherwise, this property is identical to app.locals.

This property is useful for exposing request-level information such as the request path name, authenticated user, user settings, and so on.

---

Save

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.locals.username = req.username;  
 res.locals.authenticated = true;
 next();
});
```

To retrieve the variable

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 if (res.locals.authenticated) {
  console.log(res.locals.user.id);
 }
 next();
});
```

### Approach 2:

Attach your variable to the req object.

```
req.username = username;
```

Approach 1 is the most recommended way to achieve what you are looking for.

Hope this will help you :)